# OnActionExecutionAsync "result = new NotFoundObjectResult" does not change the result

Tags: c#, action-filter, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to use ActionFilters to capture the result in my api call and change it if needed.

But it appears to change only the object i pass not the result type. (from OK to BadRequest)

```
return Ok(await _Data.Remove());
```

The above code in my controller leads to my filter:

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var resultContext = await next();

        Guid userId = await _data.GetId();
        BaseModel baseModel = (BaseModel)((ObjectResult)resultContext.Result).Value;

        if (baseModel.ApiResponse == ApiResponse.AllGood)
        {
            BaseModel m = _data.GetBaseModel(userId);
            m.ApiResponse = baseModel.ApiResponse;
            resultContext.Result = new OkObjectResult(m);
        }
        else if (baseModel.ApiResponse == ApiResponse.NotFound)
            resultContext.Result = new NotFoundObjectResult(baseModel);
        else
            resultContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(baseModel);


    }
```

The model is correctly captured and i can check against its contents. And i can change it and pass it back. But it always goes back to the controller and then returns the "ok" with the new model.
What i want is it returning BadRequest

I have tried putting doing this:

```
resultContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(baseModel);
```

As you can see from the above code, but it does not work.

Comment: I suspect the idiom you are showing, is intended for BEFORE you call next() (all examples I find do it that way.) i.e. a placed Result would prohibit next() from carrying on.
  Further, throwing an exception there, instead, DOES abort the action (but with a http-500 code).
  I haven't solved it yet, but have same issue as you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot get it to work, is because this approach isn't possible (in the general case, at least).

The async variant of the ActionFilter combines both the pre and post variants of the synchronous variant, in one callback, by giving you next().
Once you have called and successfully returned from next(), you are in 'executed' land, not 'executing' land anymore.

The trouble is, if next() has started sending the response to the client, it is too late to change the response. Your receiving client may already sit with 'http 200 ok' in his hand!

You can observe this, by trying to write to the response in context.HttpContext.Response (You can set the Http Status Code on it, and use WriteAsync on it),
in the spot where you attempt to modify Result.
If next had already started the response, you'll get a direct exception telling you this.
However, IF next() hadn't begun the response, you may actually be able to control the response.

A last-resort option you have, is to throw at this point, it will (mostly) break your http response into http-500 server error. This may or may not be good for your client.

Lastly, your resultContext actually has a 'Cancelled' attribute which you can flag.
However I don't know if that has any effect if the response has already begun (it might affect the middleware server side).

In my own case for this, I concluded it was the wrong place to solve our issue, so I moved our necessary handling to a wrapper in the controller method return statement.
I.e. you then get

`return wrapper(OK(response));`

where wrapper will decide whether to pass on OK(..) unharmed.
If you use this approach, be careful if you had

`return OK(responseWIthSideEffect(..));`

in that case, you must make sure the side effect code is forced to execute,
before your wrapper makes its decision (i.e. assuming the wrapper checks something that might depend on that side effect).